# React.createRef(); always null

Tags: reactjs

I tried looking at other posts but, can't seem to find a solution. Here is my code:

```
export default class DrumPad extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.audio = React.createRef();
    this.testRef = React.createRef();

    console.log(this.testRef.current);
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={this.testRef}

        className="drum-pad"
        id={this.props.id}
      >
        <h1>{this.props.keyTrigger}</h1>
        <audio
          ref={this.audio}
          src={this.props.sourceUrl}
          className="clip"
          id={this.props.keyTrigger}
        ></audio>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm doing the Drum Machine Project in freeCodeCamp. I'm currently stuck here. I'm trying to trigger the audio with a click, and from my research it seems that I need to use `ref` to make this work. But I'm stuck. I keep getting `null` when I `console.log()` the `ref.current`.

Comment: refs will only be attached in the first render. if you `console.log` inside `render` you should see the value updating

Comment: Or log it in `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Instead of createRef use useRef hook

Comment: @Freestyle09 You can't use hooks in a class based component. `createRef` is the correct way.

Comment: I haven't studied hooks yet anyway...

Comment: so i tried inside render and it is still `null`.. but in `componentDidMount()` i did get the values. can i ask for advice where to go from here?

Comment: actually i did it. it worked!!! 

```handleClick() {
    this.audio.current.play();
  }
```
question: was I really supposed to add `componentDidMount()` in order to make this work?

Comment: nevermind that again. I deleted `componentDidMount()` and it's still working somehow. I can't believe it. I'm pretty sure i've beein trying this.audio.current.play() earlier.. hmm.. thanks guys!!!